# How to make a compressed file directly usable as a regular file?

Tags: bash, unix, compression, named-pipes, unzip

We have a custom compressor for genomic data called CRAM, and althogugh it provides superior compression people are afraid to use it, because it is not-so-easy to handle with bioinformatic tools as "regular" files. We would like to allow compressed file to be used for example as parameters to scripts, be opened in GUIs, etc. just like classic files.

Like a named pipe or block device file that automatically executes the unzip command whenever it is read from. If it is easy to copy from system to system (to email, sftp, etc. it), it would be even better.

Our current solution:

1. let's say we have two commands, cram and uncram (you can substitute gzip and gunzip here), and an input file fileX.
2. we compress:

   cram < fileX > fileX.cram
3. we create self extracting archive for cram:

   echo "uncram < fileX.cram" > fileX.cram.sex
   chmod +x fileX.cram.sex
4. we use it as a parameter(s) in tools:

   mytool <(fileX.cram.sex)

now it is almost easy-to-use except for the "<()" notation, and the fact that you cannot immediately open it in a GUI.

Any ideas how to make the process transparent?

Answer (score 2):

You could try providing a simple wrapper around each command that processes your files:

```
$ mytool () {
>  command mytool <( "$1" )
> }
$ mytool fileX.cram.sex
```

The `command` builtin allows you run the original command, rather than the function that shadows it.

Note that `fileX.cram.sex` isn't a self-extracting archive; it's just a shell script that has a hard-coded input file.

Comment: that seems like a good solution, if you know what tools other people will use. Unfortunately there are a million things people could do with the compressed files...

you are right this is not self-extracting. Self extracting could be:

#!/bin/bash
tail -c+71 < $0 | uncram
exit 0
-----append after this----
<<<cram file to be appended here>>>

note: the character length up till -----append after this---- is exactly 70 bytes.

the only problem with the above that it would break the cram (zip) file specification if passed to the uncram (unzip) tool.

Comment: the above code with better formatting:
`#!/bin/bash;
tail -c+71 < $0 | uncram;
exit 0;
-----append after this----
<<<cram file to be appended here>>>

btw: how do I put linebreaks in the comment?