# Emulating 'named' process substitutions

Tags: bash, unix, named-pipes, process-substitution

Let's say I have a big gzipped file `data.txt.gz`, but often the ungzipped version needs to be given to a program. Of course, instead of creating a standalone unpacked `data.txt`, one could use the [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) syntax:

`./program <(zcat data.txt.gz)`

However, depending on the situation, this can be tiresome and error-prone.

Is there a way to emulate a **named** process substitution? That is, to create a pseudo-file `data.txt` that would 'unfold' into a process substitution `zcat data.txt.gz` whenever it is accessed. Not unlike a symbolic link forwards a read operation to another file, but, in this case, it needs to be a temporary named pipe.

Thanks.

PS. [Somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020461/how-to-make-a-compressed-file-directly-usable-as-a-regular-file)

---

**Edit** (from comments) The actual use-case is having a large gzipped corpus that, besides its usage in its raw form, also sometimes needs to be processed with a series of lightweight operations (tokenized, lowercased, etc.) and then fed to some "heavier" code. Storing a preprocessed copy wastes disk space and repeated retyping the full preprocessing pipeline can introduce errors. In the same time, running the pipeline on-the-fly incurs a tiny computational overhead, hence the idea of a long-lived pseudo-file that hides the details under the hood.

Comment: Would mounting the zip using [`fuse-zip`](https://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/) be an option for you?

Comment: @hek2mgl Interesting.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean a long-lived file system entry which, whenever opened, will run `zcat ...`, rather than an explicit named pipe such as `mkfifo data.txt; zcat data.txt.gz > data.txt`, correct?

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for the suggestion, but it's only a partial solution. The ungzipping was a toy example, in reality the substitutions are more complex and involve several piped processes, etc.

Comment: @chepner Yes, correct.

Comment: @artem Ok, thanks for clearification. As in UNIX everything is a file this will be possible. But process substitution looks already perfect imo. Can you clearify: `However, depending on the situation, this can be tiresome and error-prone.` ?

Comment: And `./program <(zcat data.txt.gz)` can even be more efficient without forking: `./program <(exec zcat data.txt.gz)`

Comment: @hek2mgl Can you provide an example of how this can be achieved? The actual use-case is having a large gzipped corpus that, besides its usage in its raw form, also sometimes needs to be processed with a series of lightweight operations (tokenized, lowercased, etc.) and then fed to some "heavier" code. Storing a preprocessed copy wastes disk space and repeated retyping the full preprocessing pipeline can introduce errors. In the same time, running the pipeline on-the-fly incurs a tiny computational overhead, hence the idea of a long-lived pseudo-file that hides the details under the hood.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, what you are describing does not exist, although it's an intriguing idea. It would require kernel support so that opening the file would actually run an arbitrary command or script instead.

Your best bet is to just save the long command to a shell function or script to reduce the difficulty of invoking the process substitution.

Comment: Yes, when I told in comments `Everything in UNIX is a file, it is possible` I meant at least with kernel support. However, I think using kernel support here, would likely be a too large weapon for a too small problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a spectrum of options, depending on what you need and how much effort you're willing to put in.

If you need a single-use file, you can just use `mkfifo` to create the file, start up a redirection of your archive into the fifo, and and pass the fifo's filename to whoever needs to read from it.

If you need to repeatedly access the file (perhaps simultaneously), you can set up a socket using netcat that serves the decompressed file over and over.

With "traditional netcat" this is as simple as `while true; do nc -l -p 1234 -c "zcat myfile.tar.gz"; done`. With BSD netcat it's a little more annoying:

```
# Make a dummy FIFO
mkfifo foo

# Use the FIFO to track new connections
while true; do cat foo | zcat myfile.tar.gz | nc -l 127.0.0.1 1234 > foo; done
```

Anyway once the server (or file based domain socket) is up, you just do `nc localhost 1234` to read the decompressed file. You can of course use `nc localhost 1234` as part of a process substitution somewhere else.

It looks like this in action (image probably best viewed in separate tab):

[image: netcat server demo]

Depending on your needs, you may want to make the bash script more sophisticated for caching etc, or just dump this thing and go for a regular web server in some scripting language you're comfortable with.

Finally, and this is probably the most "exotic" solution, you can write a FUSE filesystem that presents virtual files backed by whatever logic your heart desires. At this point you should probably have a good hard think about whether the maintainability and complexity costs of where you're going really offset someone having to call `zcat` a few extra times.